# Multiple conditional if() statements in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement

I know this is going to seem like an unforgiveable sin, but I have **150 variables**, and I want to create an **if function** that does the following:

```
if(a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0....) {
  //do this
} else {
  //do this instead
}
```

**However**, when I set one of the if statement conditions (i.e `b!=1`), whilst the others are still the same (`a!=0`, `c!=0`), the else function is still run, even though it should be the initial `//do this` instead of the `//do this instead` (see code snippet above).

My question is:

**1.** Is there a reason why it is not working, and if there is, how do i fix it?
**2.** Is there a simpler way to do that without having to list all 150 variables `!=0 && !=0` *etc*..?

Cheers

Comment: If you use an array or a collection to store the data instead of 150 variables, then yes, it is way easier :).

Comment: You have to wrap your data structure.. Having 150 variables in your code is an indication of coming disaster, I don't want to live to witness the results..

Comment: That just means that the `b` condition isn't the one that made the statement `false`.  Perhaps you want "or" instead of "and"?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are trying to achieve, because I'm sure we can help you come up with a better design for it. Possibly, you can simply use an array to hold all 150 values, and loop through them.

Comment: As for your error, are you saying that when one of your variables is not 0, the else statement runs? That is because you use &&. ALL of them must be true for it to pass. If you want it to pass when only one is true, then use ||.

Comment: I see cobertura complaining about branch coverage...

Comment: Could I ask what application are you doing? I think it might be a design flow that forces you into such a ridiculous things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely it would be simpler to do something like this:

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

values.add(val1);
values.add(val2);
// And so forth...

boolean pass = true;

for (Integer v : values) {
    if (v != 0) {
        pass = false;
        // You could log which variable failed here...
    }
}

if (pass) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With an array and a loop and a boolean. Review your arrays... chances are... your teacher wouldn't have you create 150 integer variables.

```
int[] integers = new int[150];
integers[0] = 1; // Set your like 150 variables like this
integers[1] = 2; 

boolean isAllNotZero = false;

for(int i = 0; i < integers.length - 1; i++) {
   if(integers[i] != 0) {
     boolean isAllNotZero = true;
   }
}

if(isAllNotZero) {
  // Do something 
} else {
  // Do something else
}
```

Comment: If only this was a school project :)- I'm doing this in my own time out of my own interest. However, you're solution is interesting

Comment: kudos to you. make sure you understand arrays!

Comment: Your logic is backwards (given your variable name). and, if someone is testing for not allZero it's best to leave the loop when that condition is reached (why look for the keys after you've found them)

Comment: next suggestion, don't use negative logic - you'll thank me later (`boolean isAllZero = true;` set to false when an `integer[x]` isn't zero then break from  loop - still no need to keep processing when you've found the exception)

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not quite sure what you mean by "set one of the if statement conditions".  But if you mean that the `b`-related test evaluates to true while the others still relate to false, then the behaviour is intended.  You're using a logical AND, `&&`, to join your conditions.  Which means that the overall condition is true if and only if **all** of the individual conditions are true.

If you want the first block to be executed when *any* of the individual conditions is true, then you use should use an OR (`||`) instead.

2) An `if` statement always requires a single boolean condition - which in this case you've formed from a conjunction of 150 individual conditions.  If you need to inspect 150 fields to reach the overall decision, then *somehow* these will all need to be accessed.

However, you might be able to make it easier on yourself.  For one thing, if the `a` and the `b` etc., are part of an object, then you can provide a nice public method that describes what the condition is, and hides the nasty details away (e.g. `public boolean isReadyToExecute()`).

Also, if you have 150 variables, chances are they're all instances of the same sort of thing.  Say, for example, you're tracking 150 files to see whether they've been generated.  Instead of having variables like:

```
private boolean fileReady1;
private boolean fileReady2;
// ...
private boolean fileReady150;
```

You can use an array (or some other collection) instead:

```
private boolean[] filesReady = new boolean[150];
```

Now you don't have to spell out every variable by hand, in order to come up with your boolean condition:

```
public boolean isReadyToLoad() {
   for (int i = 0; i < filesReady.length; i++) {
       if (!filesReady[i]) {
           // Found a file that wasn't ready, so we're not ready overall
           return false;
       }
   }
   // Got through all the files without finding an unready one
   return true;
}
```

---

The exact approach will depend on the nature of your problem.  But I reckon that some combination of *information hiding* (i.e. wrapping things in nice methods) and *loops* will cover anything you need to do.

(And don't forget that wrapping things in methods can be nested.  Perhaps the first 20 fields represent one set of things, the next 30 represent another, etc.  Then you could wrap each of *these* in a method, and implement `isReadyToLoad()` as something like `allFilesLoaded() && status.isSignedOff() && userDao.allUsersHavePasswords()`...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `stream`.

```
List<Integer> vars = new ArrayList<>();
vars.add(a);
vars.add(b);

if (vars.stream().noneMatch(v -> v == 0)) {
   // No variable = 0. Do something
} else {
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to say without knowing more details about your solution. A [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) may help you.

Comment: -1 from my side---Ahh,here comes the man to implement K-map for 150 variables... Have you even done that for more than 6 variables???

Comment: just 22500 fields to fill out ^_^

Comment: Maybe 150 variables would not be needed if K-map was used. It was a suggestion based upon vague problem description.

Comment: @JeffMiller-So,you wrote a new research paper for implementing K-map for function of 150 variables into something less,HUH??? Seems more tough than solving `NP vs P` problem!